# Why macro F1 measure can't be calculated from macro precision and recall?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I'm interested in calculating macro f1-score by macro precision and recall manually. But the results aren't equal. What is the difference in the final formula between f1 and f1_new in code?
Would you explain by formula exactly?

```python
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 1, 1, 0]
y_pred = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 0, 0]

p = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
r = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
f1_new = (2 * p * r) / (p + r)

f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')

print(f1_new == f1) 
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, because the average of $f$ is not generally $f$ applied to the average.  Here, the macro averaged f1 score is the average of the f1 scores for the two classes, but the f1 score is a nonlinear function (the harmonic average) of precision and recall.

Consider:

```py
p_1 = precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
p_0 = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=0)
r_1 = recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
r_0 = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=0)
f1_1 = 2*p_1*r_1/(p_1+r_1)
f1_0 = 2*p_0*r_0/(p_0+r_0)

print(
    f1_1 == f1_score(y_true, y_pred),
    f1_0 == f1_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=0),
    f1 == (f1+f0)/2  # the macro-average of the classes' f1 scores
)
# all True
```